# How can we add custom rules for coverity tool?

Tags: c++, static-analysis, coverity

I want to add some custom rules in order to eliminate certain false positives and to add certain rules of my own (say 3 level locks should be shown as warning, uninitialized variables should not be shown as warnings, etc).

How can I add my custom rules to coverity?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you’re asking how to write custom checkers using the Coverity Extend SDK, but actually just need to change the behavior of existing built-in checkers.  The first should be well-documented behind the paywall (an onsite course is even included in some corporate deals, which is how I took it), but in my experience should be the *last* thing you get around to—there’s a far faster return from existing checkers.

Changing the behavior of individual checkers is covered in the documentation for their configuration options (also paywalled), though it’s not clear whether the existing options will cover what you want, in which case you may need to file an enhancement ticket and wait in hope.  I cover this, probably in more generality than you care about, in my *Dr Dobbs* article, http://pobox.com/~flash/Deploying_Static_Analysis.pdf.